Pandoc table of contents: unnumbered parts and numbered chapters
I have a book I'd like to convert from Markdown to epub via Pandoc. The book is all plain text and does not contain any figures, formulas, or code. I need it to consist of several unnumbered parts with each part divided into chapters; the chapter numbering does not renew with each new part. So something like:
Book Title
 - First Part
   - 1. First chapter title
   - 2. Second chapter title
 - Second Part
   - 3. Third chapter title
   - 4. Fourth chapter title
   - 5. Fifth chapter title
 - Third Part
   - 6. Sixth chapter title 

With all chapters in separate files, I have something like this for part 1:
# First Part {-}

for the first file in which just the part heading is specified, and then

## First chapter title

Lorem ipsum dolor etc etc


for all the chapters (that's a setup for one directory in which the part is contained, and I have several of these directories). And I also have a title file in the root.
The command pandoc -o draft.epub title.txt part1/*.md --table-of-contents --number-sections  --top-level-division=part  outputs a table of contents that looks like this:
Book Title
 - First Part
   - 0.1 First chapter title
   - 0.2 Second chapter title

Which is not what I need, it has these weird zeroes. But if I try to shift the heading level with --shift-heading-level-by=-1, then the part entry First Part takes over the place of the title, so it's now like
First Part
 - 1. First chapter title
 - 2. Second chapter title 

That's not what I need either.
How can I achieve the desired effect? Top-level headers (#) as parts, second-level headers (##) as chapter titles, parts are unnumbered but present in the ToC, and chapters are numbered like 1, 2, etc and not 0.1, 0.2, so on.

Pretty sure --top-level-division doesn't have any effect on epub/html output. Not sure if there's a better way, but you could just remove --number-section as well, and write a custom CSS counter to your liking. See https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#epub-styling

The pandoc command-line interface isn't flexible enough to handle this case. However, pandoc allows to modify the document programmatically via Lua filters, and we can leverage that to get what we need.
The following Lua filter basically uses pandoc's default numbering method, but then updates the generated numbers to use the desired scheme. Use it by writing it to a file number-sections.lua and call pandoc with --lua-filter=number-sections.lua instead of --number-sections.
local struct = require 'pandoc.structure'

local fix_number = function (num)
  return num and num:gsub('^0%.', '') or nil
end

function Pandoc (doc)
  -- Create numbered sections
  doc.blocks = struct.make_sections(doc.blocks, {number_sections=true})

  -- Return the document with modified numbering
  return doc:walk {
    Div = function (div)
      local header = div.content[1]
      if not header or header.t ~= 'Header' then
        -- not a section div; return it unchanged
        return div
      end

      -- set the numbers attributes
      header.attributes.number = fix_number(header.attributes.number)
      div.attributes.number = fix_number(div.attributes.number)

      return div
    end
  }
end


Example document:
---
title: Look at this nice and meaningless title
---

# Part I {.unnumbered}

## Chapter 1

## Chapter 2

# Part II {.unnumbered}

## Chapter 3

## Chapter 4

The output of pandoc --to=html --lua-filter=number-sections.lua example.md is
<h1 class="unnumbered" id="part-i">Part I</h1>
<h2 data-number="1" id="chapter-1">Chapter 1</h2>
<h2 data-number="2" id="chapter-2">Chapter 2</h2>
<h1 class="unnumbered" id="part-ii">Part II</h1>
<h2 data-number="3" id="chapter-3">Chapter 3</h2>
<h2 data-number="4" id="chapter-4">Chapter 4</h2>

and the TOC is generated accordingly.
